# How to trigger a email based on particular field (boolean) changes in DE by cloud pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, triggered-send

I need some help & clarification about - how to trigger an email based on particular fields changes in Sendable DE by custom cloud landing pages? - Can I go to triggered email option in email studio interaction tab or create an send email event in automation studio & journey builder (which one is simple) and where can I track email info?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to trigger these emails when the field are being updated or it can be an automation running every hour/day?

Comment: I need to trigger these emails immediately when the field updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger an email using cloudpages you mainly have two options:

1. Trigger the email via [AMPscript and the SOAP Web Service API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createTriggeredSend.htm)
2. Use [Cloudpage with Smart Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_use_cloudpages_to_admit_contacts.htm&type=5) to push people in a journey

Example of option 1:

```
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "TriggerSend_Name")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber") 
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @Email) 
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @Subkey)

IF NOT IsNull(RequestParameter("Prenom_Contact")) THEN
    SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "Prenom_Contact")
    SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", @Prenom)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)
ENDIF      

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
       RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ELSE
ENDIF
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Jeremy. Actually, I designed the cloud pages fully custom subscription center replica for multiple brands and to store data in DE. so I can't go with 2 ones. In 1 option there, we defining triggeredSend Definition - I have some doubt 1. how to choose email?

Comment: You don't choose the email but the trigger send. See my example.

Comment: If I can't select an email means - which email are getting triggered by your example.  @jeremy